# How to add dynamic formControlName in AngularJs2

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I am making forms through form builder in angularjs2, I want to add `formControlName` property/attribute of form element like this:

```
   <input type="text" formControlName={{'client_name' + i}} placeholder="Required" />
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I also want to put the validity message beside input element like this:
How do I make the client_name inside the ngIf condition block dynamic as well?

```
<div *ngIf=“! userform.controls['client_name'].valid”>
  Client Name is Not Valid
</div>
```

It should have same value as `{{'client_name' + i}}`

Comment: All that's missing are "" around `{{'client_name' + i}}` It also might try to actually do addition, but that's an easy fix.

Comment: Neat! Thanx :D been stuck for a while thanx a ton.

Comment: Hi Please see my edit as well, would be grateful if u can help? :)

Comment: Where did you get stuck? did you add the fields to the formgroup?

Answer (score 2):

Please use`[formControlName]='client_name + i'` instead of `formControlName={{'client_name' + i}}`

And use `userform.controls[client_name + i].valid` instead of `userform.controls['client_name'].valid`

For More Information: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form